# Fastest way to handle a submit button with a variable in it?

Tags: python, html, forms

I've got a form with a bunch of items. Beside each item is a "Remove" button. When one of buttons is pressed, I need to know which one so that I know which item to remove.

The way I have it now, each button is named `remove-#` where `#` is the index of the item. In order to grab the `#` though I have to loop over *every* POST value, check if the key starts with `remove-` and if it does, parse out the integer.

Is there any method that would be faster than `O(n)` where `n` is the number of post vars?

---

Not that `n` is so large that this would become an expensive operation, but mostly because I'm curious.

Also, before I get any answers that suggest I use JavaScript and put an onclick event on each button to move the index into a separate hidden input.... I'm trying to do this *without* JavaScript.

Comment: the name can be `remove[]` on all the elements to send. and u can access them as an array in the serverside

Comment: @lbu: Nope. I think that's a PHP thing, and it won't work anyway, because only *one* submit button gets sent.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to put each remove button in a separate form, with a hidden value with a constant name and the value indicating which item to remove.

Comment: But alas, I cannot because there are other inputs on the page that need to be preserved. I need it to submit everything so that I can send it back again to refill them.

Answer (score 1):

If the POST values are stored in a dict you could turn this around and instead of looking for something that looks like a remove-# you generate all remove-# and try to use them to index the dict. That would limit the search to O(m) where m is the number of elements that can be removed.

Comment: Aha! Clever! The first legit answer. And I know the value of `m` so I can limit my search space.

Answer (score 0):

This really is the domain of Javascript.  However adding onclick isn't a great way to do this.  Use HTML5 data attributes and unobtrusive listeners.. For example, in JQuery/HTML5

```
<input type='button' class='remove-button' name='remove' data-remove-attr='5'>

$('.remove-button').live("click", function() {
  alert($(this).attr("data-remove-attr")); // Alerts 5.
});
```

Despite the data- being an HTML5 thing, it is backwards compatible with old IE, etc as they always allowed arbitrary dom attributes.

Edit: Note this is O(1) if as your action you did $('#remove-'+id).hide();

Comment: Same idea. Still trying to avoid JS. And frankly, I find using an invalid HTML attribute worse than using an onclick event. **Edit:** Nevermind. I didn't know `data-` was an HTML 5 thing. I guess it's not *invalid* then, but relying on HTML5 is even worse than my no-JS rule. We're not living in an ideal world here. I'm trying to assume *neither* JS is enabled, or their browser is HTML5 compatible.

Comment: Even tho older browsers aren't HTML5 compatible, they allow you to store arbiitrary (non-standard) data in the DOM anyways - this works all the way back to IE6 as far as I've ever found..